# Strange ios error showing UIDocumentPickerViewController (or some popups)

Tags: ios, swift, ios16, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have an iOS app using SwiftUI to develop its views.

With some native popups (as the one of SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: windowScene) and the Files App Browser I'm getting a strange error.

I open the rate popup this way:

```
if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: windowScene)
}
```

And I open the Files App (outside SwiftUI view, inside a Presenter) this way:

```
  var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        let types: [UTType] = [UTType.text,
                               UTType.vCard,
                               UTType.zip,
                               UTType.gzip]
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: types)
    } else {
        let types = [String(kUTTypeText),
                     String(kUTTypeVCard),
                     "com.pkware.zip-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-tar-archive"]
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
    }
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    if let view = self.view as? UIViewController {
        
        view.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Debugging with my iPhone 13 Pro, iOS 16.2 I get this error:

```
2023-02-25 13:17:50.692899+0100 MyApp[64438:13560256] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:63301 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a57fc _AXGetPortFromCache + 932
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a79b0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 772
    2   UIKit                               0x00000002174491f0 D9354398-E9A6-3296-9512-BF67ADF23501 + 782832
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f45a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f605c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fe10c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 988
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fee34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010780bcbc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 740
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1b98 start_wqthread + 8
)
2023-02-25 13:17:50.699031+0100 MyApp[64438:13560256] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:63301 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a57fc _AXGetPortFromCache + 932
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a79b0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 772
    2   UIKit                               0x00000002174491f0 D9354398-E9A6-3296-9512-BF67ADF23501 + 782832
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f45a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f605c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fe10c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 988
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fee34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010780bcbc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 740
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1b98 start_wqthread + 8
)
2023-02-25 13:17:50.700365+0100 MyApp[64438:13560256] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:63301 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a57fc _AXGetPortFromCache + 932
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ba7a79b0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 772
    2   UIKit                               0x00000002174491f0 D9354398-E9A6-3296-9512-BF67ADF23501 + 782832
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f45a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077f605c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fe10c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 988
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001077fee34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010780bcbc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 740
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de9d1b98 start_wqthread + 8
)
```

With my iPhone X, ios 15.3.1 and with the emulators this error doesn't appear. Is this an iOS 16 bug?

Comment: Yes, I get this with the photo picker, which is similarly out of process. Does your code work anyway? If so, just ignore the console feedback.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AX+Lookup+problem+-+errorCode%3A1100+error%3APermission+denied+portName%3A%27com.apple.iphone.axserver%27 this is a common issue.

Comment: Yes, my code works, but I was worried about the error. If this is a common issue then I'm happy :)

Comment: Click the link I gave you and see for yourself. If you are satisfied, delete the question. Do feel free to file a bug report with Apple!